# JAWS not reading angular 2 interpolation

Tags: accessibility, angular2-routing, wai-aria, uiaccessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am running JAWS screen reader on my page and it automatically starts to read the page as soon as it loads. But the divs which contain angular 2 interpolation are skipped being read out.
I am not too sure if the processing is still happening and that it is why it reads the DOM elements whatever is available to be read by then. Is there a way to control it and make it read the page in an order?

Here is a sample where it reads the labels for the check box before reading the angular content:

```
<div [ngClass]="col-md-6" class="c2">
            <div class="productDetails-name" style="cursor:default!important" >
                {{productDetails?.ProductName}}
            </div>

            <div class="c1">
            {{ productDesc}}
            </div>

            <div class="prdDetails-compareAddtoCart">
                <span class="newCheckbox" tabindex="0" (keyup)="OnPressCompareClick(productDetails?.Id,$event)">
                    <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" [value]="compareListCount" [checked]="isAddedInCompare(productDetails?.Id)" (change)="OnChangeUpdateProductCompareList(productDetails?.Id, $event)" (click)="onCompareClick($event)" style="display:block;margin-top:14px;position:absolute;" aria-label="Select to add the item to comparison list"
 id="chkAddCompare" >

                    <label  tabindex="-1" class="compare-defaultFont" for="chkAddCompare" >&nbsp;Compare</label>

                </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <span class="prdDetails-separator"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span class="compare-defaultFont">Qty.&nbsp;</span>
                <addToCart tabindex="-1" [product]="productDetails" [isProductDetails]="true" (setAddToCartParams)="setAddToCartParams($event)"></addToCart>
            </div>
```